# Success criteria for games

Tags: charts

If I develop/publish a video game and start distributing it, how do I know if it's success or failure? I guess it should be something like music publishing industry, i.e. some billboards, top 100 charts, etc, based on sales figures, income, distribution rate, etc. I guess that there should be some trade associations that would publish sales or distribution rate data periodically - and that would be reliable and comparable data.

Such charts exist for other software, for example, there are a few well-known browser usage charts, such as:

- [StatCounter Global Stats](http://gs.statcounter.com/)
- [W3Schools' Browser Trends](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp)
- [NetMarketShare](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=0)

I did a bit of homework research, but, alas, I couldn't find any reliable source of information on these. So far I've found:

- [A list of best-selling games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_video_games) and [it's PC games only section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_PC_video_games) in Wikipedia that is based on information extracted bit-by-bit from various less-than-reliable sources, such as various gaming magazine reviews. Only the number of copies sold are analyzed. Most of the time, these metrics look useless: for example, I can't get sales-by-year or sales-by-geography data and thus I can't determine, for example, what was the most popular (okay, most widely sold) game of year X.
- [Video game sales wiki](http://vgsales.wikia.com/) does pretty much the same - it analyzes lots of various sources, such as industry forums and fairly rare published company reports. It analyzes only console video gaming market, without PC gaming.
- [VGChartz](http://www.vgchartz.com/) provides much more interesting and well-organized data - they provide week-by-week breakdown and per-region breakdown of sales figures - however (a) I couldn't find any info on how do they obtain their data and how reliable they are, (b) they don't have information on lots of games.

So, I guess the question is: is there a reliable, well-organized source of data for sales figures or some other measurement of success for video games? Ideally, I'd like a reliable and trustworthy list of "top X games", periodically (annually, quarterly, etc) published for a long time. May be some industry journal publishes such a list?

*(I'm not sure that Stackoverflow is the best place to ask this question - maybe "programmers", "gaming" or "gamedev" would be a better choice, but I'm really not sure)*

Comment: All of those choices would be better than SO.  Voting to close.

Comment: Gamedev for sure, but I answered anyways from a business point of view.

Comment: Is it possible to automatically migrate a question to another StackExchange site? I've seen some questions migrated...

Answer (score 2):

Easy - how much money did you make?  if it was more than you put into it, then it was a success.